# Calculate the next sum $\sum\limits_{k=3}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{3k+1}{k(k+1)}(x-1)^k$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, summation-method

> Find the next sum 
>   $$\sum_{k=3}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{3k+1}{k(k+1)}(x-1)^k$$

I do not know how to solve this. I’ve tried to split the fraction into two fractions and use $\ln(x)=\int_1^x dt/t$, but I’m stuck here. So any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: if you split the fraction in two the solution is immediate in terms of the expansion of $\ln(1-x)$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: $\boxed{-\frac{7}{6}x^2+\frac{13}{3}x-\frac{31}{6}-\left(\frac{x-3}{x-1}\right)\ln{x}}$

Answer (score 2):

***Hint***

$\sum_{k=3}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{3k+1}{k(k+1)}(x-1)^k$

$\sum_{k=3}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{2k + (k+1)}{k(k+1)}(x-1)^k$

$\sum_{k=3}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{k}(x-1)^k + \frac 2 {(x-1)}\sum_{k=3}^\infty (-1)^k \frac {(x-1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)}$

$-\sum_{k=3}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{(x-1)^k}{k}+ \frac 2 {(x-1)}\sum_{k=3}^\infty (-1)^{k+2} \frac {(x-1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)}$

$-\sum_{k=3}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{(x-1)^k}{k}+ \frac 2 {(x-1)}\sum_{k=4}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac {(x-1)^{k}}{(k)}$

$- \frac {(x-1)^3}{3}-\sum_{k=4}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{(x-1)^k}{k}+ \frac 2 {(x-1)}\sum_{k=4}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac {(x-1)^{k}}{(k)}$

$- \frac {(x-1)^3}{3}+ (-1+ \frac 2 {(x-1)})\sum_{k=4}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac {(x-1)^{k}}{(k)}$

Then take a look at the developpement of ln (x) for the serie...

Comment: The environment `$$\begin{align} A &= B \\ C &= D \end{align}$$` is perfect for this kind of math

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChaseRyanTaylor this will improve my knowledge of latex

Comment: This [MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) should be of great use to you.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{1-y} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty y^k \hspace{3cm}\text{|y|<1}\\
\dfrac{1}{(1-y)^2} &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty ky^{k-1} \hspace{3cm}\text{|y|<1}\\
\dfrac{3y}{(1-y)^2}+\dfrac{1}{1-y} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (3k+1)y^k \\
\dfrac{2y+1}{(1-y)^2}&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (3k+1)y^k \\
\dfrac{4-y}{(1-y)^2} &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (3k+1)y^{k-1} \hspace{2cm}\text{here take integration}\\
\dfrac{3y}{1-y}-\ln(1-y) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{3k+1}{k}y^k \hspace{3cm}\text{0<y<1}\\
\dfrac{3y}{1-y}-\ln(1-y) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{3k+1}{k(k+1)}y^{k+1}\\
-2\ln(1-y)-y\ln(1-y)-2y &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{3k+1}{k(k+1)}y^{k+1} \hspace{3cm}\text{0<y<1}\\
\end{align}
now set $y=1-x$ and drop two first terms. So
$$\sum_{k=3}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{3k+1}{k(k+1)}(x-1)^k=\color{blue}{-\frac{31}{6}+\frac{13}{3}x-\frac{7}{6}x^2-\frac{2}{1-x}\ln x-\ln x}$$

Comment: where is the $ (-1)^n $ factor ?

Comment: $y=1-x=-(x-1)$.

Comment: Isolate $k=0$ and bring it to left side!

Comment: Please can you say to me what have you done in this step:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{2y+1}{(1-y)^2}&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (3k+1)y^k \\
\dfrac{4-y}{(1-y)^2} &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (3k+1)y^{k-1}
\end{align}

Comment: And, in this one. I suppose you integrated
\begin{align}
\dfrac{3y}{1-y}-\ln(1-y) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{3k+1}{k(k+1)}y^{k+1}\\
-2\ln(1-y)-y\ln(1-y)-2y &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{3k+1}{k(k+1)}y^{k+1}
\end{align}
But I obtain another result 
\begin{align}
\dfrac{3y}{1-y}-\ln(1-y) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{3k+1}{k(k+1)}y^{k+1}\\
-3\ln(y-1)-(y-1)\ln(1-y)-2y &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{3k+1}{k(k+1)}y^{k+1}
\end{align}
Thank you.

Comment: First integrate and change the index of summation

Comment: Could you expand on your explanation?

Comment: Try more. You can!